# How to create a token using eosio.token contract?

Tags: smart-contract, tokens

I am trying to follow the tutorial, deployed eosio.token contratc to eosio.token account. I have no problem to do the following:

```
eos.transaction({
  actions: [
    {
      account: 'eosio.token',
      name: 'create',
      authorization: [{
        actor: 'eosio.token',
        permission: 'active'
      }],
      data: {
        issuer: 'eosio.token',
        maximum_supply: '7000000 EOS'
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

However, using any symbol other than 'EOS' or 'SYS' caused the error:

> method: 'throw_datastream_range_error' } http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain/get_currency_stats {"code":"eosio.token","symbol":"EOP"}
>   { Error: {"code":500,"message":"Internal Service Error","error":{"code":8,"name":"out_of_range_exception","what":"Out of Range","details":[{"message":"read datastream of length 14 over by -12","file":"datastream.cpp","line_number":6,"method":"throw_datastream_range_error"},{"message":"Error unpacking field version","file":"raw.hpp","line_number":368,"method":"operator()"},{"message":"error unpacking eosio::chain::abi_def","file":"raw.hpp","line_number":616,"method":"unpack"}]}}

Comment: Have you tried with decimal places '7000000 EOP' -> '7000000.0000 EOP'?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in eosjs, https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/issues/110.

Using cleos to set contract works for me.